# How to fill up the rest of the screen height using TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm using Vue with Tailwind and want to create a "NotFound" view page. The content on this router view should be in the center on the screen. Above the router view is a navbar component so I have to take care for the height when centering it.

First, I tried to use `h-screen` for the router view

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.8.12/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <div class="bg-yellow-400 py-8">
    my navbar
  </div>
  <div class="bg-green-400 flex justify-center items-center h-screen">
    this content is not centered on screen
  </div>
</div>
```

but as you can see the content in the green container is not in the center of the screen. Next I tried to work with `h-full`

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.8.12/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="h-screen">
  <div class="bg-yellow-400 py-8">
    my navbar
  </div>
  <div class="bg-green-400 flex justify-center items-center h-full">
    this content is not centered on screen
  </div>
</div>
```

but unfortunately this still doesn't fix it. Does someone know how to correctly fill up the rest of the screen height so the router view will have a height of `100% - navbarComponentHeight`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use flexbox like below:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.8.12/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen">
  <div class="bg-yellow-400 py-8">
    my navbar
  </div>
  <div class="bg-green-400 flex justify-center items-center flex-grow">
    this content is centered on screen
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now what if you have a nav bar in one div, but then 2 divs within the nav bars sibling div? How could we go about making sure the 1st child div of the nav bar's sibling div takes up the rest of the screen height? My head is spinning.